# Is there a way to compile and execute C# code from C++ program?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono

I am looking for cross-platform (Windows and mono) solution to compile and execute C# code (with mono) from C++. Is there any way of doing that?
I also need to a way of communicating with that assembly after, for example execute methods and etc.
In Windows we can use CLI/CLR for that, but this will not work on linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of thing is possible. I don't believe this functionality is built into mono. Have a look at the repl loop implementation CsharpRepl. http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Comment: Looks like this is impossible, and in general my idea is not so good, because windows and linux are different platforms, so i should not use C# on linux (in my opinion). Thanks for answer